# Compare first column of one file with the first column of second and print associated column of each if there was a match

Tags: bash, awk, system-administration

I have two files, I need to compare their first columns and if the match is found, I'd like to output the corresponding values from both files.

Similar to this Q but I'd like to print columns from both files not one: [How to compare multiple columns in two files and retrieve the corresponding value from another column if match found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004437/how-to-compare-multiple-columns-in-two-files-and-retrieve-the-corresponding-valu)

File1.txt

```
adeqY   33.7
AIsLX   65.6
AmuBv   1589.0
aZMIx   84.4
```

File2.txt

```
AmuBv foo
iwwlp bar
adeqY hi
qUbJZ bye
```

Output

```
hi 33.7
foo 1589.0
```

I have the following `awk` command but I only managed to print the second column match from File2:

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} ($1) in a {print $2 a[$2]}' File1.txt File2.txt`

`a[$2]` doesn't want to print

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a){print $2,a[$1]}' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
foo 1589.0
hi 33.7
```

***Problem in your attempt:*** You was going good only thing in `FNR==NR` condition your `a[$1]` is NOT having any value it only created its index in array `a` so that is why it was not able to print anything when 2nd Input_file is being read.

Comment: It works so good! Thank you. Now I need to do the same in python.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do there is essentially an INNER JOIN on two tables stored in text files and the Linux join command is designed for just that.

Try:

```
join -t' ' -1 1 -2 1 -o 2.2,1.2 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) 
foo 1589.0
hi 33.7
```

Explanation:

- The field separator is specified as -t. I assumed that your data is separated by a single space in these text files.
- The `-1 1 -2 1` is says to join on the first field for the left-hand side file and the first field on the right-hand side file.
- The `-o 2.2,1.2` defines the fields you want to return. The second field from the second file then the second field from the first file.
- Finally, note that I sorted the input files as the files need to be sorted by the field that you intend to join by for the Linux join to work.

See also this blog ([ref](https://alexharv074.github.io/2018/09/22/the-four-sql-joins-using-linux-join-and-sort.html)).

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that, once you're printing results in the last awk statement, the `a[]` array is no longer in scope, hence why that second value is not printing.

Maybe there is another way to do this `awk`, but this is the solution I came up with:

```
for each in $(comm -1 -2 <(awk '{print $1 }' file1.txt | sort ) <(awk '{print $1 }' file2.txt | sort) ); do echo $(grep $each file2.txt | awk '{print $2}') $(grep $each file1.txt | awk '{print $2}') ; done;
```

This outputs:

```
foo 1589.0
hi 33.7
```

Explanation:

- Run a `comm` command on the two files.
- The two "files" given to `comm` are actually process substituted, so that they are sorted first (`comm` expects sorted input) and only the first column is shown.
- The `-1 -2` parameters to `comm` tells it to only print the common elements from the files (it can show elements unique to first file, unique to second file, or common to both)
- Once you have the common elements from both files, `for each` of those common elements, go ahead and grep each of the files for the line where it appears, and show only the second value, using awk.

So, in the end, we needed a bash `for` loop, `sort`, `comm` and `awk` multiple times. Not the most elegant solution probably, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Try Perl variant

```
$ cat eskp1.txt
adeqY   33.7
AIsLX   65.6
AmuBv   1589.0
aZMIx   84.4

$ cat eskp2.txt
AmuBv foo
iwwlp bar
adeqY hi
qUbJZ bye

$ perl -F"\s+" -lane 'BEGIN { %kv=map{split /\s+/ } qx(cat eskp1.txt) } { print "$F[1] $kv{$F[0]}" if $kv{$F[0]} } ' eskp2.txt
foo 1589.0
hi 33.7
```